# comparing two XML with different number of elements using XMLUnit

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xmlunit

I have two xmls, that needs to be compared. Number of elements in both the xml's may vary. Say for example consider below two xmls:

XML1:

```
<Students>
                <Name Type="PG">
                    <GivenName>David</GivenName>
                    <Surname>John</Surname>
                </Name>
                <Name Type="PG">
                    <GivenName>Naveen</GivenName>
                    <Surname>S</Surname>
                </Name>
                <Telephone AreaCityCode="BLR">
                    <PhoneNumber No="+91-9643542222"/>
                </Telephone>
               <Telephone AreaCityCode="BLR">
                    <PhoneNumber No="+91-9643542258"/>
                </Telephone>
                <Email>David.JOHN@gmail.com</Email>
                <Email>Naveen.S@gmail.com</Email>
                <Address Type="PT">
                    <AddressLine>40 DICKENSON ROAD</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>BANGALORE 12</AddressLine>
                </Address>
                <Address Type="TP">
                    <AddressLine>DOUBLE ROAD</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>BANGALORE 20</AddressLine>
                </Address>
</Students>
```

XML2:

```
 <Students>
                <Name Type="PG">
                    <GivenName>David</GivenName>
                    <Surname>John</Surname>
                </Name>
                <Name Type="PG">
                    <GivenName>Naveen</GivenName>
                    <Surname>S</Surname>
                </Name>
                <Telephone AreaCityCode="BLR">
                    <PhoneNumber No="+91-9643542222"/>
                </Telephone>
               <Telephone AreaCityCode="BLR">
                    <PhoneNumber No="+91-9643542258"/>
                </Telephone>
                <Email>David.JOHN@gmail.com</Email>
                <Address Type="PT">
                    <AddressLine>40 DICKENSON ROAD</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>BANGALORE 12</AddressLine>
                </Address>
                <Address Type="TP">
                    <AddressLine>DOUBLE ROAD</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>BANGALORE 30</AddressLine>
                </Address>
</Students>
```

In XML2, number of `email` element is only one, but where as in XML1 it is two. My task is to compare the content of `AddressLine` element irrespective of number of `email` elements. I have written a piece of code for obtaining this as below:

```
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true); 
 DetailedDiff detailledDiff = new DetailedDiff (XMLUnit.compareXML(XML1, XML2));
    detailledDiff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndTextQualifier());
    List<Difference> list = detailledDiff.getAllDifferences();
    for (Difference difference : list) {
        if(difference.getTestNodeDetail().getXpathLocation() == null)
            System.out.println("control: "+difference.getControlNodeDetail().getXpathLocation());
        if(difference.getControlNodeDetail().getXpathLocation() == null)
            System.out.println("test: "+difference.getTestNodeDetail().getXpathLocation());
    }
```

Even though there is a change in `AddressLine`, it doesn't print the `addressLine` XPath. Please help me out in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot reproduce your same results with your same XMLs and tester. For me, it returns just `control: /Students[1]/Email[2]`. I've tried xmlunit-1.3  and xmlunit-1.5. Check the input files you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe you have some whitespace (blanks, newlines, etc) too much in one of your files. To ignore whitespace, add this line at the beginning of your tester:

```
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
```